Laravel Pulse with GuzzleHttp/Client and custom base_uri
I'm trying to add laravel-pulse-guzzle-recorder to my Laravel Pulse, to record
Slow Outgoing Requests when using a GuzzleHttp/Client instead of the builtin Http facade.
Docs say you need that the Client class must be resolved using the service container app but... now I can't find a way to set my custom configs to the Client as I did until now:
$config = [
    'base_uri' => config('app.ikaiaki_url'),
    'headers' => $headers,
    'handler' => $handlerStack
];
$client = new Client($config);

I can't find any example of instantiating Client using app() and setting a custom base_uri to it. I tried what follows, but my configs are ignored:
/** @var Client $client */
$client = app(Client::class, $config);

According to docs, Client is immutable, so there's no way to set variables after creation.

Maybe there's some more elegant solution than mine, but I find it works writing my service provider this way:
namespace App\Modules\Services;

use App\Modules\Client\MyClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Utils;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use MuhammadHuzaifa\LaravelPulseGuzzleRecorder\Recorders\LaravelPulseGuzzleRecorder;

class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {}

    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->bind(MyService::class, function($app) 
        {
            $client = $app->make(MyClient::class);
            return new MyService($client);
        });

        $this->app->singleton(MyClient::class, function ($app) {

            // handler added for Laravel Pulse:
            $stack = HandlerStack::create(); // will create a stack with middlewares of guzzle already pushed inside of it.
            $recorder = new LaravelPulseGuzzleRecorder();
            $stack->push($recorder->middleware());

            $headers = [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ];
            $config = [
                'base_uri' => config('app.my_url'),
                'headers' => $headers,
                'handler' => $stack
            ];
            $client = new Client($config);

            return new MyClient($client);
        });
    }
}

I added the stuff for the recorder (the handler) in my custom client creation, using a plain new. It works.
